# How to pass Dictionary TKey and TValue to a method one by one in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, tuples, hashset

I have a `Dictionary` in code as:

```
SqlCommand query = con.CreateCommand();
query.CommandText = @"select pid, p_title from sub_aminer_paper where pid IN (/*a long list of Pid's*/)";
SqlDataReader reader = query.ExecuteReader();

Dictionary<int, string> paper_title = new Dictionary<int, string>();   
paper_title.Add(Convert.ToInt32(reader["pid"]), reader["p_title"].ToString() );
```

And string `lines` reading a text file as:

```
var lines = System.IO.File.ReadLines(@"D:\~\research_fields.txt");
```

I want to pass Dictionary TKey and TValue to a method to be called in a `HashSet` as:

```
var similarity = new HashSet<Tuple<string, double, int>>();
similarity.Add(lines.Select(line => Tuple.Create(line, p.calculate_CS(line, paper_title.Select(item => item.Value).ToString()), paper_title.Select(item => item.Key))));
```

But this line of code giving error of some invalid arguments.
The method `p.calculate_CS(string, string)` takes two arguments of type `string`. I have to take one `string` from `lines` and one string from `Dictionary` i.e. `paper_title`. The third argument for `Tuple` is of type `int` that will be the `Key` from `Dictionary`.

Comment: can you show the code for `calculate_CS` method?

Comment: If you want to pass three params, why have you created method with two parameters? you can just add an other parameter in method's signature and then use that parameter within your method

Comment: @MuhammadAdeelZahid the method `p.calculate_CS(string, string)` has two params whereas `p.calculate_CS(string, string)` is itself 2nd param of a three params Tuple

Comment: @MuhammadAdeelZahid number of params is not the issue, the issue is how to use `Dictionary` keys and values in method calculate_CS()

Comment: The third parameter `paper_title.Select(item => item.Key)` will not give you a single integer value. Except it will give you an `IEnumerable` of `intgers` representing all keys of the dictionary

Comment: Even `paper_title.Select(item => item.Value).ToString()` will not give you what you expect out of it. It will return the type name of an `IEnumerable` which represents all the values in dictionary

Comment: Your problem is, you have created dictionary but you don't know which value from dictionary you need to pass in parameter

Comment: @MuhammadAdeelZahid I need to pass each and every value from dictionary to the method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96151/discussion-between-taufel-and-muhammad-adeel-zahid).

Answer (score 0):

From the discussion in comments, I think your code should look something like

```
  var similarity = new HashSet<Tuple<string, double, int>>();
    foreach(var key in paper_title.Keys){
        similarity.Add(lines.Select(line => Tuple.Create(line,
   p.calculate_CS(line, paper_title[key]), key))); 
    }
```

This code will iterate through each key in your dictionary and will call `calculate_CS` method with appropriate attributes.

Comment: @MuhammadAdeelZahid--I have used to `Union` instead of `Add` now its fine but one issue is `paper_title[key]` is not required here inside `p.calculate_CS()` method. I need the value of key that is of string type inside this method

Comment: Because arguments for `calculate_CS` method are (string, string)

Comment: @MuhammadAdeelZahid--your answer is fine but only issue is I need Value of that Key instead of `paper_title[key]`

Answer (score 0):

The TKey and TValue can be passed one by one to method using following:

```
Dictionary<int, string> paper_title = new Dictionary<int, string>(); 
paper_title.Add(Convert.ToInt32(reader["pid"]), reader["p_title"].ToString() );
var similarity = new HashSet<Tuple<string, double, int>>();
foreach(KeyValuePair<int, string> item in paper_title)
{
    similarity.UnionWith(lines.Select(line => Tuple.Create(line, p.calculate_CS(line, item.Value), item.Key))); 
}
```